# android - issue with static method

Tags: java, android, static

In one class I call a function from another class which is on another .java file.

This is the function

```
public void make_a_call(String phonenumber) {
    Intent phone_call = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:"+phonenumber));
    startActivity(phone_call); 
}
```

The problem is this function requires it to be non static because of startActivity, but when I call this function from another class, it says that, to call it, this function needs to be static.

How can I fix this?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other class needs a reference to a context that will be used to start the activity. One solution is to pass a reference to the activity (the one that contains `make_a_call`) to the code in the other class. Another possibility (if the other class is a custom view, for instance), is for it to use `getContext()` to obtain a context and then modify `make_a_call` to be `static` but to accept a context as an argument:

```
public static void make_a_call(Context context, String phonenumber) {
    Intent phone_call = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:"+phonenumber));
    context.startActivity(phone_call);
}
```